# Accessing the OnSuccess event for AJAXRefreshView

Tags: 2013, javascript, ajax

I am doing a **AJAXRefreshView** on a particular site page after a button is clicked. The list in question is being refreshed however I am unable to apply some custom styles that have been applied to the list.

I am looking for a way to tap in to the `OnSuccess method` without doing things like editing SP.JS or Core.JS etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to get this working like I originally intended, so I was forced to refresh site using:

```
SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
```

This was not so bad since the user only sees the site refresh and not the entire SharePoint.